# How to know which standard my Wi-Fi connection is currently using

Tags: wireless, network-manager

My laptop has capabilities for 802.11n connections.

With my previous router, I could transer data faster than 54Mb/s.
Now I have D-Link router and for some reason the maximum connection speed is 54Mb/s, which implies that the connection was established with 802.11g.

How can I check which standard (g or n) has been established? Is there any command to get that information? (nm-applet does not give any information about that in the connection information window).

Answer (score 22):

The utility `iw` shows the used bitrate and indicates the used IEEE 802.11 standard by its listed capabilities.

Read your interface name from the `iw dev` output, and use it within `<name>`.

```
iw dev <name> link
```

[Example output](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#getting_link_status) when associated with a legacy (non-802.11n) AP:

```
    tx bitrate: 36.0 MBit/s
```

["MCS index"](https://mcsindex.com/), indicating a 802.11n AP:

```
    tx bitrate: 300.0 MBit/s MCS 15 40Mhz short GI
```

"VHT", indicating support for 802.11ac:

```
    tx bitrate: 86.7 MBit/s VHT-MCS 8 short GI VHT-NSS 1
```

Compare this with the Linux driver [802.11n table](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/ieee80211/802.11n). You'll see how the example "MCS 15 40Mhz short GI" 300 MBit/s corresponds to a row within the "HT40 rates" for the "short 400ns GI" column.

To see what your Wi-Fi adapter is generally capable of, independent of the AP link, run `iw phy0 info` (synonymous to `iw list`) and look for keywords like HT (802.11n) / VHT (802.11ac, (Very) High Throughput), MCS (Modulation and Coding Schemes) index number and long/short GI (Guard Interval).

For more explanations, continue with [this](https://superuser.com/a/945540/744005) Super User answer.

Comment: Nice answer! How would I recognize an [802.11e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11e-2005) connection? Does the output contain "QoS"?

Comment: [WMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions) is a subset of 802.11e. `iw dev <name> station dump` will list if WMM is in use for the established link

Comment: What about for WiFi 6 (802.11ax) and WiFi 6E?  How would you tell if your connection is one of those?

Comment: look for the HE (High Efficiency) letters and its MCS index to correlate. See this [spreadsheet link](https://semfionetworks.com/blog/mcs-table-updated-with-80211ax-data-rates/) for theoretical max bitrate per index. For example "HE MCS index 8, 2 spatial streams (depends on your device support), short (0.4µs) Guard Interval and 40Mhz channel width" is a theoretical 360 Mbit/s max

Comment: This is the only answer, that helped to recognize the connection mode (802.11n, 802.11ac etc.). It was a big disappointment for me to know, that regular Linux means do not allow to easily detect such basic info for WiFi connection!

Comment: this answer is for users specifically interested in the standard. Common Linux distributions (with nmcli and network-manager / gnome-settings) will show you the max bitrate per connection and AP

Answer (score 4):

1. try `lshw -C network`
2. try `iwconfig` and search for `Bit Rate`
3. try `lspci | grep -i wireless`
4. `wavemon` is the ultimate tool for wireless

Comment: first, wavemon is awesome!
unfortunately, none of those tools supply which standard the connection using (g or n).
54Mbit can be g and n...
does anybody knows what can be the reason that the interface is not lock down the n standard?
at my mom's laptop, it is connected at 65Mbit, and my computer has n capabilites (again, with other routers working with n)

Answer (score 0):

With `sudo lshw -C network` you should be able to see which modes you wifi adapter supports. But since your problem seems to be the router find out your wifi adapters name using `iwconfig` (should be something like `wlan0` or `eth0`). Then try a `iwlist wlan0 scan` (replace `wlan0` with your adapters name). It will list the supported bit rates. If the highest is is 54Mbit/s your router doesn't seem to support the n standard.

This way you can find out if you should be able to connect with the n standard. Sadly I know no way to find out what standard the present connection uses.

Answer (score -2):

this question was already answered: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62265/linux-find-wifi-networks-protocola-b-g-n-version-of-all-available-access-point

in short issue: `iw dev wlan0 scan` and the output should indicate which access point has what capabilities around you.

More details are in the mentioned link.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are two different questions: The question you linked to is about which standards the AP *supports*, while this question wants to know the standard that the AP and the connected host are *actually using*.

Comment: if you're very strict about it - then yes these are two different questions. however your equipment can detect only standard it can use - so there's no _real_ practical difference when detecting what can you and the AP negotiate upon - this is de-facto the standard you're going to use when connection to this particular AP. (Or maybe I'm wrong?)

Comment: Here's an example: `iw dev wlan0 scan` tells me (indirectly) that the AP supports up to IEEE 802.11ac. Now I'd have to find out which standards the wireless chip in my host supports. How to do that (`iw phy`) is not part of your answer and the answer you linked to. Assuming that I know now that my host supports up to IEEE 802.11n, I'm probably right in thinking that the AP and the host will use IEEE 802.11n. But I want to be *sure* what the actual connection uses. That's the question. Addendum: To my knowledge, the output of `iw dev wlan0 scan` is independent of the host's capabilities.