# Creating a WPA3 Wi-Fi hotspot fails all the time

Tags: wireless, 20.04, hot-spot, wpa2, wpa3

When I am trying to create a Wi-Fi hotspot that should offer a `WPA3 Personal` encryption, all CPUs are running mad for a few seconds before Ubuntu tells me that the creation of the hotspot failed. Everything works fine when I am using `WPA & WPA2 Personal` encryption but I would like to avoid that type of encryption.

What can I do in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

WPA3 is not supported on your wireless adapter.

[From this answer:](https://askubuntu.com/a/191668) you can check its model with `sudo lshw -C network`